# Merge 2 lists in a Functional Reactive way

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reactive-programming, rx-java

Let's imagine the following object :

```
class People {
  public int id;
  public String name;
  public Date dateOfDeath;
}
```

I have 2 lists of people.

In the first one, a People object has its ID and NAME properly set. In the second one, a People object has its ID and DATEOFDEATH properly set.

I need to combine the 2 lists in order to have a single list with a full People object (name and date of death).

In a full procedural way, this could be done with a double for loop like this :

```
for (People fullPeople : firstList) {
  for (People peopleWithDateOfDeath : secondList) {
    if (peopleWithDateOfDeath.id == fullPeople.id) {
      fullPeople.dateOfDeath = peopleWithDateOfDeath.dateOfDeath;
      break;
    }
  }
}
secondList = null;
// first list is good :)
```

How can I implement this in a functional way? I am using Rx-Java but any example with Java 8 Streams is easily convertible.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity by building a map of `id` to `dateOfDeath`:

```
Map<Integer, Date> deaths = secondList.stream()
    .collect(toMap(p -> p.id, p -> p.dateOfDeath));

fullPeople.stream()
    .filter(p -> deaths.containsKey(p.id))
    .forEach(p -> p.dateOfDeath = deaths.get(p.id));
```

Or, if you want to avoid mutating existing people:

```
List<People> mergedPeople = fullPeople.stream()
    .map(p -> deaths.containsKey(p.id) 
            ? new People(p.id, p.name, deaths.get(p.id))
            : p
    ).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
List<People> persons = 
        names.stream()
             .map(p -> new People(p.id, p.name, dates.stream()
                                                     .filter(pd -> pd.id == p.id)
                                                     .map(pd -> pd.dateOfDeath)
                                                     .findFirst()
                                                     .orElse(null))
             )
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `names` is the list of persons having the names and `dates` is the list of persons having the date of death. This assumes that the `People` class has a 3 argument constructor taking the id, name and date of death.

For all person with names, the person having the same id is looked up in the other list with `filter` and we map the result to the `dateOfDeath`. If a match is found, the date is returned, otherwise, `orElse` is invoked and `null` is returned.

Note that this will not merge any person that is present in the `dates` list but not in the `names` list.

Sample code:

```
List<People> names = new ArrayList<>();
List<People> dates = new ArrayList<>();
names.add(new People(1, "Name 1", null));
names.add(new People(2, "Name 2", null));
dates.add(new People(1, null, new Date()));
dates.add(new People(3, null, new Date()));

List<People> peoples = codeFromAbove();
System.out.println(peoples);
// prints
// [[id=1, name=Name 1, date=Sun Oct 18 19:48:58 CEST 2015],
// [id=2, name=Name 2, date=null]]
```

with:

```
class People {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Date dateOfDeath;
    public People(int id, String name, Date dateOfDeath) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.dateOfDeath = dateOfDeath;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[id="+id+", name="+name+", date="+dateOfDeath+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this clean example. In the procedurale way, the inner loop can be optimized by removing any people already matched to avoid having to search deeper and deeper into the dates list. In my case, this could help a lot because I know that both lists will be both sorted on the ID. Any way of doing the same optimization in the functional way ?

Comment: @pdegand59 Misha's answer can do that for you: you can invoke `deaths.remove(p.id)` instead of `deaths.get(p.id)`.